# Datepicker get val

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

Where is my mistake? I have date picker like this:

```
<div id="tarih" style="display:none;margin:auto;padding:10px">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="Click to Schedule..." ><br>
<input type="text" class="input-mini" placeholder="Hour" id="hour" maxlength="2"><br>
<input type="text" class="input-mini" placeholder="Minute" id="Minute" maxlength="2">
</div>
```

and my jQuery:

```
if($("#tarih").val() == "" || $("#hour input.input-mini").val() == "" ||$("#hour input.input-mini").val() == ""){
alert("no date selected");
}
else{
alert("ok");
}
```

Although I choose a date, alert no date selected.

I add some code where is the wrong ?

Comment: And where did you place that code, or in other words, how are you initalizing the datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if($("#tarih input.datepicker").val() == ""){
```

---

You need to get value of `datepicker` element which `input.datepicker`.

---

`$("#tarih")` --> refers to element with id `tarih`.

`$("#tarih input.datepicker")` -->refers to element `input.datepicker` inside id `tarih`.